# R Markdown Crashing with `Eval` in code chunk

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am experiencing an unexpected behavior from manually running code in RMarkdown: Whenever we use `eval =` in r code chunk: it doesn't find the arguments inside it (no matter local or in `params`).

The R session also crushes after running anything with `eval`. However, knitting the document does not produce the error.

Here's a sample RMD file. `chunk1` is able to run without issues. But running `chunk2` or `chunk3` produces this error:

```
Error in eval(ele) : object 'local_var[OR]params' not found`.
```

After the error, running anything (e.g. `chunk4`) will crash the rstudio session.

````
---
title: "tmp"
output: html_document
params:
  eval_ind: TRUE
  test: 3
---

```{r chunk1}
local_var <- 1+as.numeric(params$test)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r chunk2, eval = local_var ==4}
2+2

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r chunk3, eval= params$eval_ind}
summary(cars)
```

```{r chunk4}
1+1
```
````

Here's my session info:

```
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8 LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 
[8] LC_NAME=C LC_ADDRESS=C LC_TELEPHONE=C LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
  [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0 yaml_2.1.19 knitr_1.20
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is some typos in your header:

```
---
title: "tmp"
output: html_document
params:
  eval_ind: TRUE
  test: 3
---
```

`title` needs to not be indented, and `test` should be indented if you want it to be a `param`, not just another header entry.

Making those changes fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Good observation. I was trying to make a code block so I accidentally added those space in (will fix those now). Were you able to replicate the error?

Comment: No, it seems to run fine for me once you fix those bugs in the header. It’s a strange problem, since those `knitr` conditions like `eval=` only get run when knitting the document. If you run the code manually (like with the `Run Current Chunk` arrow, it just runs the code in the console